# Create custom right-click menu for OS X app, developed on Linux

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-yosemite, right-click

I am creating an app for Mac OS, but it is being built on Linux.  Because of this, I am not able to use tools such as Xcode, and I am not developing in swift.  Rather, the .app directory is being put together according to Apple's documentation, and the entrypoint/executable of my app is a shell script.

I need to customize the menu which appears when you right click on the app (either on the dock icon or in Finder).  Is there a way to do this, without using cocoa, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

The menu I believe you are referring to is called "***Services***".

In order to add a menu item there for your application you would create a script to enable including it there.  Xcode isn't needed or required, however, you'll need to know at the very least some basic AppleScript or Javascript to accomplish what you want. (see examples from the link)

> ↳ [Mac Automation Scripting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/MakeaSystem-WideService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH46-SW12)

Comment: "Services are triggered from the Application Name > Services menu, or from contextual menus that appear when you Control-click on text, files, and other kinds of data." Does this work with one app or the Dock?